# laravel mix could not compile a scss file containing compass/css3 import

Tags: laravel, compass

I have a file named `main.scs` that imported a `general.scss` file that has at the first line this :

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

As you can see I imported `compass/css3` to use some predefined mixins.

Of course all of them are in a larvel project. larvel have a built-in `Mix` library to compile scss and other type files.

Also I wrote these to `webpack.mix.js` file :

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main.scss', 'public/main/css');
```

But when running `npm run production` command I got this error:

```
 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss

Module build failed:
@import "compass/css3";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
Parent style sheet: D:/wamp/www/loverspay/resources/assets/sass/_general.scss
      in D:\wamp\www\loverspay\resources\assets\sass\_general.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

Even I installed compass in the project directory But there is still that problem

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have compass library installed inside `node_modules` directory you can try to import it like this:

```
@import "~compass/css3";
```

If it's doesn't help you can try to modify sass `includePaths` config variable (laravel mix has a third option to pass additional config):

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main.scss', 'public/main/css', {
  includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './relative/path/to/compass')]
});
```

Comment: First I run `npm install compass`. then tried `@import "~compass/css3";` but got same error. then I added `includePaths: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/compass')
    ]` But also got the same error .